# How to install 2 or more WordPress Blogs with the same mysql database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

How to install 2 or more WordPress Blogs with one mysql database in the same site with different paths sub and root domain?

note:  i want to use each blog as a unique blog without connecting it with other blogs, for example: blog1.domain.com, blog2.domain.com, domain.com/blog3, without putting them in the same network.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you found any resources online that you need more information on how to use?

Comment: I searched on Google and sadly found nothing :(

Comment: this is such a common problem, there is LOADS of information out there. Show some effort please. https://www.google.fi/#q=wordpress+several+blogs+one+site

Comment: In fact my question not about having a several blogs on the same site, it's about how to install it more than one blog on the same site with 1 mysql database as it show with the question title, i searched in Google and found nothing helpful, try it your self.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Wordpress administration, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload WordPress to a different folder and install with a different table prefix (Installation [Step 5](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Step_5:_Run_the_Install_Script)). The two installations won't conflict. You'll have one set of tables like 'wp_posts' (if you haven't changed the prefix) and another like 'wp_blog2_posts' for table prefix 'wp_blog2_'.

But in case you want to connect the sites, share content or similar, multisite is the better option. See Wims answer.